# empty cell error while trying `=importxml`

Tags: xml, import

I'm trying to data scrape an email off a web page and I've tried every which way to write the formula but for some reason it always returns the imported content empty error.

This is the HTML section which I'm trying to scrape:

```
<p class="upv_email">
                    <span class="upv_titles">Email Address:</span> 
                    <script type="text/javascript">eval(unescape('%64%6f%63%75%6d%65%6e%74%2e%77%72%69%74%65%28%27%3c%61%20%68%72%65%66%3d%22%6d%61%69%6c%74%6f%3a%61%6d%73%61%72%79%65%72%73%6f%6e%40%67%6d%61%69%6c%2e%63%6f%6d%22%20%3e%61%6d%73%61%72%79%65%72%73%6f%6e%40%67%6d%61%69%6c%2e%63%6f%6d%3c%2f%61%3e%27%29%3b'))</script><a href="mailto:*****@gmail.com">******@gmail.com</a>
                </p>
```

and the most recent formula I've tried is (the url is in A2):

```
=importxml(A2,"//p[@class='upv_email']//a/@href")
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I assume you're trying this in Google Sheets or similar? Have you tried it using an XPath tester, such as [this one](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Google Sheets. Just tried the Xpath tester you suggested and got 

Attribute='href=mailto:*******@gmail.com' which is what I want, but when I try in Sheets it comes back as an error

Comment: Without knowing the full page, it's hard to say but I'd guess that the HTML isn't valid XML in some way. It probably doesn't have a `<?xml...>?` prefix at the top.

Comment: You're right, it says <!Doctype HTML>. Any suggestion how I alter the formula?

Comment: Actually, I've just tried a different formula and it doesn't give me the email but it does give me the string of % above it - so the importXML must work on this page.